# multiline CMD in dockerfile what does it mean?

Tags: dockerfile

I saw this in some dockerfiles, what does it mean?

```
CMD ["phpcs"]
CMD ["phpcbf"]
```

without entrypoint.

Answer (score 0):

CMD does not require an entrypoint, from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The CMD instruction has three forms:
>
> ```
> CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
> CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
> CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)
> ```

Basically, you use the entrypoint if you omit the executable parameter. In these cases it's running `phpcs` and `phpcbf` without parameters.

Comment: so if I run container without executable, second CMD gets hit. So whats the point of having two CMD instructions there?